# Changing xorg audit level

Tags: linux, logging, centos, audit, xorg

I am writing a program which needs to monitor the screen resolution of the `XServer` frequently. For this I am using every second `XOpenDisplay` to get a fresh reference to the actual settings. So far, so good.

The problem I face now is that the `XServer` stores for every request quite a bit of information in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. As the program should be able to run forever without filling up the filesystem on `/var`, I am wondering, what I can do to solve this issue.

The reason for this verbose logging is the fact that CentOS (6 + 7) starts the `XServer` with `-audit 4`, which instructs the server to log every access information in the log file.

I am now wondering, if there is a smarter way of retrieving the actual resolution of the screen. I tried from the command line `xrandr` and other tools, but they all seem to access `X` in the same way, resulting in the same amount of log entries.

So, if there is no other way, as I can't assume a specific driver configuration I could access natively, I properly have to modify the `XServer` setting. But I can't figure out how to do this.

There seems to be no global config file where the audit level is set, at least I can't find it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get both current screen resolution and events about changes and a lot more via the RandR extension.

Answer (score 0):

Xorg is started by `/usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave`.
The whole Xorg command line is pre-compiled inside the binary module.

I have successfully patched the `-audit 4` parameter to `-audit 1` simply using vi. After a restart, the steady increase of log files (Xorg and gdm) stopped.
(verified on CentOS 6.6 to 6.9)